# Android: combine PreferenceFragment with other widgets in single layout

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to have an `Activity` that shows just a few (or one) preference item(s) and some more widgets in the remaining space. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

in **/res/xml/preferences_1.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="test" 
        android:title="test" 
        android:defaultValue="false" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The layout for the activity that I'd like to contain an ui to edit this single preference:
**/res/layout/test.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.test.something.TestActivity$PrefsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View ... stuff ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the `Activity`:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from XML resource
            this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_login);
        };
    }
}
```

This should illustrate what I'm trying to achieve: having the `<fragment>` show the `PreferenceFragment` and below that still have a (or some) widget(s).

Sadly, this doesn't work as I had hoped. Instead it throws when opening the activity. The relevant part of the stack trace seems to be:

> E/AndroidRuntime(12584): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.something/com.test.something.TestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Could someone show me how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh! Later on in the stacktrace there was actually a much more helpful message. The `<fragment>` was missing an `android:id` attribute.